# Derivative of fidelity with respect to time

Tags: calculus, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, quantum-computation, quantum-information

Consider the quantum fidelity between two states defined as
$$
F(\rho(t),\sigma(t)):=\text{Tr}\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{\rho(t)}\sigma(t)\sqrt{\rho(t)}}\right)^2
$$
Does $dF/dt$ have a closed form equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not going to have a simple closed-form expression, but I'll give you some tools that you can use to build up an expression for the derivative yourself.

First consider matrix functions of the form $\sqrt{A(t)}$, where $A(t)$ is a continuously differentiable positive definite $n\times n$ matrix. (Things can get a little hairy if $A$ is not positive definite.) We wish to compute the derivative 
$
\left.\frac{d}{dt} \sqrt{A(t)}\right|_{t=0}.
$
We may suppose without loss of generality that $A(0)$ is diagonal, $A(0)=\operatorname{diag}(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$. Let $D$ be the $n\times n$ matrix whose entries are given by
$$
D_{i,j} = \left\{ 
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{\sqrt{\alpha_i}-\sqrt{\alpha_j}}{\alpha_i-\alpha_j} &\quad \text{if }\alpha_i\neq\alpha_j\\
\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha_i}}&\quad \text{if }\alpha_i=\alpha_j.
\end{array}\right.
$$ 
The desired derivative is 
$$
\left.\frac{d}{dt} \sqrt{A(t)}\right|_{t=0} = D\circ A'(0),
$$
where $\circ$ denotes the [entrywise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) product of matrices.

You can find the derivation of this in many textbooks on matrix analysis. I'll list a few here:

- Theorem 6.6.30 in $[1]$
- Theorem 5.9 in $[2]$
- Section V.3 in $[3]$

$[1]$ Roger A. Horn, Charles R. Johnson. *Topics in matrix analysis* (1991).

$[2]$ Fumio Hiai, Dénes Petz. [*Introduction to matrix analysis and applications*](https://users.renyi.hu/~petz/pdf/matrixPD.pdf) (2014).

$[3]$ Rajendra Bhatia. *Matrix Analysis* (1997).

Comment: Thanks for the starting point I'll get my hands on a matrix analysis book!

Comment: One may then make repeated use of this argument to compute the desired derivative. First differentiate $\sqrt{\rho(t)}$, then differentiate $\sqrt{A(t)}$ where $A=\sqrt{\rho(t)}\sigma(t)\sqrt{\rho(t)}$.